# Creating an Android Lockscreen & Notification Listening

Tags: android, count, notifications, overlay, lockscreen

So I am currently building a lockscreen for Android and I have come a long way in terms of the functionalities of this app. However, I am facing two issues:

1) I am currently using a timer every few seconds to refresh the count of new messages on the phone. I have a method - `getMessageCount();` - that returns the number of unread texts from `content://sms/inbox`. This method works perfectly, but I don't suppose it is very battery friendly and the phone tends to get a bit warm from the constant refresh.

I am sure there is a better way to listen for (push) notifications on the phone without the need to refresh the count each time. Any suggestions?

2) The entire app is coded in the MainActivity (there has been no need to use other classes yet), and I have managed to show the lockscreen above the default lockscreen using `getWindow().addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_SHOW_WHEN_LOCKED);`. How can I make a settings-view when accessing the app from the app-drawer, and then send the lockscreen itself to overlay the screen when the phone is locked? Right now, using the `FLAG_SHOW_WHEN_LOCKED` only works when I lock the screen above the MainActivity. If I close the app, the overlay closes as well.

Thank You in advance.